# Burst of app crashes immediately after publishing to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

Immediately after publishing a new version of an application on Google Play, I get a burst of new crashes from an unknown device called "unknown Full Android on Emulator".

Here is a screenshot from Crashlytics after the application was uploaded to Google Play. This crash did not come from a real device.

Does anyone know what this emulator is?

Crashlytics console:

[image: Crashlytics console]

A similar pattern of crashes can be seen in this screen clip from the Splunk console:

[image: Splunk console]

Comment: Is there a question here? It could be any new or rooted device with a custom ROM.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since soon after publishing a new version I see crashes almost only from this device, I'm guessing it's a `Google Play` new app publishing flow, where they `monkey test` your app.

I'm seeing crashes from Debug activities that can't be opened in the UI, but can be accessed via a direct intent, so I'm also guessing this monkey test goes over the manifest, launches random activities directly, and plays with them.

See: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html

Comment: The case related to debug activities is very interesting, I didn't know about that, so I'm now sure that it is an automated test tool

Comment: First hear of [monkey test](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html)~

Comment: Have you asked Google Play support about this? I'm experiencing similar problems with a caveat: the "devices" don't seem to support OpenGL 2, and I'm filtering out devices without OpenGL 2 support per the manifest, but these still try to run the application and obviously it crashes.

Comment: @FranMarzoa i'm not sure this is the same issue as of the OP, you should check your final manifest (after it merges with dependencies) to check if your limitation still holds. i've had some issues in the past with limiting OpenGL version in manifest, it doesn't always work as expected. see this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer#view_the_androidmanifestxml

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I have dozens of thousands of installations active and only one user has this problem and 100% of their devices are rooted and all but one are stated to be emulators. Thanks for the link, though. I'll save it for future reference.

Answer (score 9):

I also found similar issue reported on Crashlytics with a Rooted Emulator , and it's NullPointer Exception in onCreate() of an activity when I try to access a value got from getIntent(). But I always put this value in previous activity . So I guess it's launch by monkey or "adb am start" even the activity is exported = "false"