# Burst of crashes

Tags: android, crashlytics

we've published our app a few days ago on Play Store. Since then, every day, we see a short burst of crashes in Crashlytics. It takes about an hour, and it generates over 200 crashes. All with same stack trace, from different devices, and all devices are rooted.

Stack trace is this (redacted):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: get_lib_extents[742]:   795 - /data/data/our.app/lib/libsomething.so is not a valid ELF object
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

Has anyone f you seen something like that? What is it?

Comment: There's not even enough information here to speculate. Does your app do any clock-scheduled activity? (e.g. daily update check) What is this native library in your app? How is it built?

Comment: I really doubt it has anything to do with the way we build our app. This crash happens only in those bursts, never in our testing, never on other users or otgher times in production. We don;t have anything scheduled in those times each day. We suspect some chinese botnet, or whatever.

Comment: This may be automated app testing by Google, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346336/burst-of-app-crashes-immediately-after-publishing-to-google-play